# highest common factor-fewest iterations

Tags: code-challenge, number

Find the highest common factor of two(positive integer) input numbers (not greater than 5000) in the minimum number of iterations.

If you use a loop, it should increment a counter, starting at 0 for the first run. The counter should be the first statement in the loop. If you use more than one loop, they too should have a similar counter.

So

```
counter_1=0;
counter_2=0;
...
loop{
    counter_1=counter_1 + 1;
    ...
    code
    ...

    loop_nested{
        counter_2=counter_2 + 1;
        ...
        code
        ...
    }
}
total_count=counter_1 + counter_2 + ...
```

Test cases
first-number second-number-->expected-output

450 425-->25

27 23-->1

1000 1001-->1

36 54-->18

2 4000-->2

4000 2500-->500

2000 4000-->2000

99 75-->3

584 978-->2

3726 4380-->6

The code with the lowest sum of all counters for all test cases wins.
There is no restriction on program length. Of course, you can't use any standard functions. There is no restriction on the language that you use.

Also, please write the sum of counters that your code produces.

Comment: In array-oriented languages like APL, J or R, this could be done without writing any (overt) loops at all, even without using the built-in GCD function.

Comment: Heck, it can be done even in GolfScript without any explicit loops!

Comment: Voting to close because without a clear definition of "standard function" or "loop" (does recursion count? period-n quines? etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C, no loops -> 0 iterations

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define Q(n) (a % (n) == 0 && b % (n) == 0) ? (n) :
#define R(n) Q((n)+9) Q((n)+8) Q((n)+7) Q((n)+6) Q((n)+5) Q((n)+4) Q((n)+3) Q((n)+2) Q((n)+1) Q(n)
#define S(n) R((n)+90) R((n)+80) R((n)+70) R((n)+60) R((n)+50) R((n)+40) R((n)+30) R((n)+20) R((n)+10) R(n)
#define T(n) S((n)+900) S((n)+800) S((n)+700) S((n)+600) S((n)+500) S((n)+400) S((n)+300) S((n)+200) S((n)+100) S(n)
#define U(n) T((n)+4000) T((n)+3000) T((n)+2000) T((n)+1000) T(n)

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a, b, gcd;
  if (argc <= 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <num1> <num2>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  a = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (a < 1 || a > 5000) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input %d out of range!\n", a);
    return 1;
  }

  b = atoi(argv[2]);
  if (b < 1 || b > 5000) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input %d out of range!\n", b);
    return 1;
  }

  gcd = U(1) 0;

  if (gcd) {
    printf("The greatest common divisor of %d and %d is %d.\n", a, b, gcd);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find gcd of %d and %d! Inputs out of range?\n", a, b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Given that you've specified an upper limit of 5000 on the input values, this challenge can be solved in *any* language without *any* (runtime) loops just by taking a trivial solution using a single trial-division loop and unrolling it 5000 times.

I've chosen to use C, since the C macro preprocessor allows the solution to be written in a compact manner.  The macros will be expanded at compile time into a single *huge* nested ternary `?:` expression.

(If you consider the compile time macro expansion to be a loop in disguise, feel free to run the code above through the C preprocessor and consider the expanded *output* — which is also a valid C program — to be my solution.  I won't include the expanded version in this post, though, since it's huge.)

Answer (score 6):

Along similar lines to Ilmari's solution, but slightly shorter (comparing expanded versions):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define D(pn, p) (a%(pn) + b%(pn) ? 1 : (p))
#define P(p) D(p, p)
#define P2(p) D(p, p) * D(p*p, p)

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a, b, t, gcd;
    if (argc != 3) return 1;

    a = atoi(argv[1]);
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (a < 1 || a > 5000 || b < 1 || b > 5000) return 1;

    // Force an order: a <= b
    if (a > b) {
        t = a; a = b; b = t;
    }

    gcd = (a == b || a*2 == b || a*3 == b || a*4 == b || a*5 == b ||
           a*3 == b*2 || a*5 == b*2 || a*4 == b*3 || a*5 == b*3 ||
           a*6 == b*5) ? a :
            ((a|b) & -(a|b)) *
            P(3) * D(9, 3) * D(27, 3) * D(81, 3) * D(243, 3) * D(729, 3) *
            P(5) * D(25, 5) * D(125, 5) * D(625, 5) *
            P(7) * D(49, 79) * D(343, 7) *
            P2(11) * P2(13) * P2(17) * P2(19) * P2(23) *
            P(29) * P(31) * P(37) * P(41) * P(43) * P(47) * P(53) * P(59) *
            P(61) * P(67) * P(71) * P(73) * P(79) * P(83) * P(89) * P(97) *
            P(101) * P(103) * P(107) * P(109) * P(113) * P(127) * P(131) *
            P(137) * P(139) * P(149) * P(151) * P(157) * P(163) * P(167) *
            P(173) * P(179) * P(181) * P(191) * P(193) * P(197) * P(199) *
            P(211) * P(223) * P(227) * P(229) * P(233) * P(239) * P(241) *
            P(251) * P(257) * P(263) * P(269) * P(271) * P(277) * P(281) *
            P(283) * P(293) * P(307) * P(311) * P(313) * P(317) * P(331) *
            P(337) * P(347) * P(349) * P(353) * P(359) * P(367) * P(373) *
            P(379) * P(383) * P(389) * P(397) * P(401) * P(409) * P(419) *
            P(421) * P(431) * P(433) * P(439) * P(443) * P(449) * P(457) *
            P(461) * P(463) * P(467) * P(479) * P(487) * P(491) * P(499) *
            P(503) * P(509) * P(521) * P(523) * P(541) * P(547) * P(557) *
            P(563) * P(569) * P(571) * P(577) * P(587) * P(593) * P(599) *
            P(601) * P(607) * P(613) * P(617) * P(619) * P(631) * P(641) *
            P(643) * P(647) * P(653) * P(659) * P(661) * P(673) * P(677) *
            P(683) * P(691) * P(701) * P(709) * P(719) * P(727) * P(733) *
            P(739) * P(743) * P(751) * P(757) * P(761) * P(769) * P(773) *
            P(787) * P(797) * P(809) * P(811) * P(821) * P(823) * P(827) *
            P(829);

    printf("The greatest common divisor of %d and %d is %d.\n", a, b, gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Ruby

```
def gcd(a,b)
  ('x'*a+' '+'x'*b).gsub(/^(.*)\1* \1+$/,'\1').length
end
```

A completely different solution - no explicit loops either.

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 0 loops.

Some languages don't even have loops, they use recursion.

Note: if you don't use Tcl 8.6, replace `tailcall` with `return [...]`

```
proc gcd {a b} {
    if {$b > $a} {tailcall gcd $b $a}
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    tailcall gcd $b [expr {$a % $b}]
}
```

Well, and here for the people that said recursion is a loop:

```
proc gcd2 {a b {i 0}} {
    if {$b > $a} {lassign [list $a $b] b a}
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
    set a [expr {$a % $b}]
    if {$a == 0} {return $b}
    set b [expr {$b % $a}]
    if {$b == 0} {return $a}
}
```

Comment: Tail reucrsion _is_ a form of looping, really :)

Comment: Well, because of the upper limit of 5000, I could replace the tail recursion with the procedure itself.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (0 loops)

All right, after some people have posted even smarter ideas I might as well post this one, which I wrote to support my comment. It has no loops or recursion expressed in it.

```
∇GCD;divs;gcd
  divs ← {A/⍨A=⌈A←⍵÷⍳⍵}
  gcd  ← {⊃A/⍨(A←divs⍺)∊divs⍵}
  ⎕ ← ⎕ gcd ⎕
∇
```

For people who are not familiar with reading APL, I'll give all explict looping constructs that I know of below:

- `:For` ... `:EndFor` (for loop)
- `:While` ... `:EndWhile` (while loop)
- fn`¨`list (apply *fn* to each element in *list*)
- fn`⍣`*N* (apply *fn*  *N* times)
- fn`⍣`condfn (apply *fn*, until (*condfn*( *x*, *fn*( *x* ) ) is true)
- `{`...`∇`...`}`: recursion (`{`...`}` is a function, `∇` refers to the function it is used in)

Explanation of the program:

- `divs`: (get divisors of a number, in descending order)

  - `A/⍨A=⌈A`: select from `A` those elements where `A` is equal to `ceil(A)`
  - `A←⍵÷⍳⍵`: ...where `A` is the right argument (`⍵`) divided (`÷`) by the numbers from 1 to `⍵` (`⍳⍵`)
- `gcd`: (get the greatest common denominator of two numbers)

  - `⊃`: get the first (thus, biggest, see above) element of:
  - `A/⍨`: the elements selected from `A`, where...
  - `(A←divs⍺)`: `A`, which is the divisors of the left argument,
  - ...`∊divs⍵`: ...is a member of the divisors of the right argument.
- `⎕ ← ⎕ gcd ⎕`: output (`⎕ ←`) the GCD of input (`⎕`) and input (`⎕`).

Comment: Hi marinus, some of the characters are rendering as the 'not found' square when I look at this on Safari (OS X) – is there any chance you could clarify?